# Making divs constantly move randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a shooting game for children, where they have to shoot the correct number (depending on the question) when it appears. My problem is at the moment the numbers appear one at a time but I would like to make it so that the canvas is constantly populated with numbers that keep moving around like the shapes in this example... http://sheppardsoftware.com/mathgames/earlymath/shapes_shoot.htm

```
function moveRandom(id) {

var cPos = $('#container').offset();
var cHeight = $('#container').height();
var cWidth = $('#container').width();

// get box padding (assume all padding have same value)
var pad = parseInt($('#container').css('padding-top').replace('px', ''));

// get movable box size
var bHeight = $('#' + id).height();
var bWidth = $('#' + id).width();

// set maximum position
maxY = cPos.top + cHeight - bHeight - pad;
maxX = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth - pad;

// set minimum position
minY = cPos.top + pad;
minX = cPos.left + pad;

// set new position
newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX);

$('#' + id).css({
    top: newY,
    left: newX
}).fadeIn(2000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + id).fadeOut('fast');
        window.cont++;
    }, 1500);
});
```

Here is the version I have created http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does it work if you replace the `css()` method with `animate()`?

```
$('#' + id).animate({
    top: newY,
    left: newX
}).fadeIn(2000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + id).fadeOut('fast');
        window.cont++;
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: No it does the same thing @Tim S

Comment: That sort of works. Is there a way to have all the divs on the canvas at once, constantly moving? @Tim S

Comment: @Milo-J better like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/7/ - your min and max seems to be a bit off though